# Obtain reference to element angular 4

Tags: angular, element

I have a component whos template looks like:

```
..blabla
 <img md-card-image src="..">
..blabla
```

How do I obtain a reference inside my component.ts so that I could change it's src using angular 4?

Comment: You don't. Instead, you use [src]="someDynamicExpression", and whe the dynamic expression value changes, the src changes automatically. This is called "binding", and is at the core of angular.

Comment: You can get a reference with a [Template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars), but as @JBNizet said, it's better to use binding for that task

Answer (score 31, accepted):

in HTML:

```
<img #img md-card-image src="..">
```

in TS:

```
@ViewChild('img') img: ElementRef;
```